# Eddy-current input to op-amp misses reading at times

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, signal-processing, inductance

The problem is only in the input stage of the [op-amp](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP6L91-1R-2-4-Data-Sheet-DS20002141C.pdf).

**Edited:** removed reference to "eddy-current" and changed to "reluctance".

The reluctance-current is generated from two coils by ferrous movement passing through them.  The coils are 10 ohm each with 0.254 mH. The current coming out of them is a sine wave that goes positive and negative. The circuit works 95% of the time as it is, but at times it seems that the difference between the two op-amp inputs (2 and 3) is not enough to result in an output.

On the bench, if I simulate things and feed a positive 3 V pulse into **J1** going to Pin 2 of the op-amp and also ground **J2** (going to pin 3) then it works 100% of the time.  Of course, in real life the current is not only positive.

I suspect that when the positive and negative current is generated in the form of a sine wave, at times the input via J2 going into pin 3 of the op-amp overrides J1 going into Pin 2 of the op-amp, thus the op-amp does not put out any amplified signals.  Should I change R2 to a lower value like 2-3k, or should I add also a capacitor in series between J2 and pin 3 of the op-amp?

**Update**:  I made a small breadboard with the changes suggested below and jerry-rigged it to the PCB, but was not able to get any reliable readings.  I will recreate the entire OP AMP front-end circuit on a larger breadboard.

Will also consider the suggestions made by @Kartman and @EJE which led me to these links: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/71jqlq/variable_reluctance_waveform_op_amp_circuit_issues/         http://www.megamanual.com/ms2/pcb.htm

A comparator may be a better solution, but for now will continue with the OP AMP.  I am a bit confused about using the (-) or (+) OP AMP inputs correctly.  Any benefits to gain in my case to sue one over the other, besides non-inverting (+) and inverting (-)?   For now, I think I will be looking at increasing resistor R4 to around 2k-3k which will still give a 5x gain with R1. A larger R4 value I believe will lead to a larger voltage change.  I was concerned that a larger resistor will attenuate the signal generated from the coils by "suppressing" the current.

Also, wondering if I should have the two coils in series (instead of parallel, currently) with on end tied to ground and the other to one OP AMP input?   Something like this: [image]

It's a comparator with a 1/2VCC input from voltage divider, and other input from two coils in series with zener and regular diodes and load resistor.

[image]

[image: -20mV to +60mV]

[image: updated board with DC center added]

Comment: Diodes should be added to protect inputs as in §4.1.2. Also, R4 seems a bit too low and I should lower R2 and add a capacitor and some "offset".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Not familiar with "§4.1.2. ", what is it?   If I add a diode with a forward drop of 0.7V how does the 60mV signal get through?  I will try to lower R2 to 3K and will add a 4.4uF ceramic in series with the + input (J2).  I tried in the past to increase R4 and had problems getting a reading.  This may be fixed with a proper setup on the positive side input?  Do I need an offset in order to keep the two inputs separated so they won't drop below each other?

Comment: Think that R4 & C4 is "derivative" function. Would simulate it to know the "knee" frequency. Also, what is the peak voltage input at max?

Comment: The frequency range of the two pulses is 200Hz-26KHz.    The peak voltage of the eddy-current sine wave signal is around 70mV and drops down to -40mV.

Comment: @TommyS - Hi, You said in response to an earlier [comment](/posts/comments/1664658) from Antonio51: "*Not familiar with "§4.1.2. "*". That means section 4.1.2 in the [MCP6L91 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP6L91-1R-2-4-Data-Sheet-DS20002141C.pdf) which you linked in the question, entitled "Input voltage and current limits" on page 13 of the current version of the PDF file. In particular see figure 4-1 on that page, which shows the diodes referred to by Antonio51. I hope that helps.

Comment: What's the amplitude of this so-called eddy current?

Comment: @SamGibson Ok. Sorry. I forgot to say that I added the link to datasheet ... It is not the only problem. I added in answer to explain what happens if there is not a DC point add.

Comment: @Andyaka shamed to admit but did not think to measure nor tried to calculate the current's amplitude. Since it's momentary (two pulses) I think I would need to use my oscope and a shunt resistor.  I do have a 0.1 Ohm resistor that may I can use. https://www.tek.com/en/blog/how-can-an-oscilloscope-measure-current

Comment: @SamGibson  thank you very much!  I see, the two diodes (assuming 0.7V forward voltage drop) will "dump" current/voltage from the inputs into VDD?

Comment: Sounds like a reluctor sensor. Do you want to amplify the voltage or derive a digital output? Use a comparator if you want a digital output. Use two comparators if you want the positive and negative edges. I woukd suggest you don’t involve Eddy - he is innocent. I think it was Michael and his law of induction to blame for the observed effect!

Comment: @Kartman good sense of humor :) And you are correct: although I have not heard that term before, it is in essence a "reluctor sensor". I just want to measure the period/freq of the two pulses that are generated from the two coils by a singular ferrous object/trigger passing them. The MCU uses interrupts connected to internal MCU timers to measure the period between the two pulses, leading edge to leading edge. So, need only digital. Two separate comparators?

Comment: From what @Kartman mentioned, I observed the *electronic* resemblance of Variable-Reluctance sensor is very high. The difference I would guess is that TommyS might be detecting a flux leakage with a sensor coil that does not provide a magnetic flux to the relative-moving counterpart, just detects it; probably resulting “Eddy’s” misnomer. I found an application note:  https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/1/1076.html that shows how the small hysteresis available in a RS485 transceiver (as MAX485 too) could be used for that VR-sensor being converted to Digital.

Comment: Made some updates to the main body of the question. Will be working on those. Any inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what happens with MCP6L91 op-amp (not in my database).
But here is the behavior with AD8591 (rail to rail, in my database) (AC analysis).

[image]

When the non-inverting is not polarized at 1.65V, the output is at -60db.
When "well" polarized, it is a "band-pass" as usual.

NB: Must be checked in TRANsient Analysis with sinusoidal input, for example.

[image]

In red, what happens when V8=0, as in your "setup".

I also added the behavior with the "sensor" used. AC Analysis.
No fundamental change.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the very well illustrated recommendation.  I really appreciate the thoroughness. So based on what I understand from your post, fundamentally the current OP AMP circuit is suited for the expected frequency range, but I need to add a "DC point" at the + input (pin 3) of the OP AMP. Currently the DC level on + input of the OP AMP rests at zero which causes attenuation issues when voltage/current from the two sensors are applied. That DC point should be raised from zero to a constant 1.65V.  Maybe I use a voltage divider from the VDD via 10K/10K resistors.

Comment: Right for your understanding. Voltage divider 10k/10k would be ok. Just don't forget a capacitor from the middle to the ground (>10uF would be ok). In fact, probably the input voltage is going below ground and becoming negative (not very "good" for some op-amp).

Comment: Added the updated circuit diagram in my original post.  Will modify the actual circuit, test it, and will report back.

Comment: Be aware that the gain could be too high.